# Open vim and run script upon opening

Tags: shell, vim

I'd like to have a script open a new file with vim, and, upon the file's opening (and after loading all of the .vimrc configurations and plugins, etc), run a simple vimscript command.  Just one command, actually.

I don't need to maintain a client-server connection or anything...just a one-off script upon opening.

I've tried using a custom vimrc with `-u`, but then I'm not sure how to load the default plugins as well.

Thanks!

Edit: Any type of command would work...vim script or normal mode command, because I'm comfortable hacking together my script to work with any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't tell clearly what kind of "command" you want to execute on the file.
there are some options you could take a look.

```
+{command}   //e.g vim "+1,5d" file will auto-remove first 5 lines
-c {command} //e.g vim -c "1,5d" file will auto-remove first 5 lines
-s {script} // same as you typed those characters in file, the file could be generatd by -w
-S {file}   //same as source, then you don't have to mess up with your .vimrc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute vim commands from the command line by prefixing them with `+`:

```
vim '+echo "hello"' file.txt
```

If you need do something more complicated, you'd likely want to define a function in the `vimrc` file or some other configuration, and use the `:call` command to run that function:

```
vim '+call MyFunction()'
```